# Execution of pytest script from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pytest

I want to invoke the execution of a pytest script from a Python based wrapper script. The wrapper script provides few objects to save logs, parse logs at the end of execution, summarizing it.

wrapper.py

```
#this is my local module to store the execution log in a single file for each run
from log import Log 
from subprocess import call

#create a object to save the log. The Log() class is defined using singleton metaclass 
log = Log()
#invoke the pytest based test script
out = subprocess.run(["pytest", "-v", "test_example.py::TestExec::test_sum", "-s"], capture_output=True)
```

test_example.py

```
import pytest
from log import Log
class TestExec():
    def test_sum(self):
        c = 3 + 4
        #trying to create another instance of log object. Due to singleton class, it should allow to use the same object id as created earlier if the process id/namespace is same as wrapper
        log = Log()
        log.info("In test_Sum")
        return
```

I explored the options available mainly:
subprocess.Popen(), subprocess.call().. all of these creates a another child process which create a new instance of Log() rather using the same due to different process (Wrapper as parent & Pytest as child) which blocks them from sharing the common namespace.

I also tried using threading.thread(). This seems to run only a function but in my case I have command line to be executed. Same with process() from multiprocessing module.

I need something similar to perl `` so that I can have the execution of pytest in Wrapper.py

Any suggestions/pointers would help.

Comment: What about calling `pytest.main()`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, pytest.main()  works well.. Thanks for it..